# join two separate parameter into one

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have SSRS report containing two separated parameter. One passing Category and second one value. And I have one field in the report for category. How to join these two separated parameter and field of the report

Parameter example

```
Category--ABC,DEF
Value   --1,2
```

SSRS Report has fields Category ABC, DEF, and later I need to do calculation

```
if category = ABC then value*xxx
                  1*XXX
```

How to use two separated parameter values in one and then use in report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer as your question is not very clear but I will assume the following....

1. You have a database table a `myCategory` column and a `myValue` column
2. You have a parameter called `pCategory` which is multi-value
3. You have a parameter called `pValue` which is a single value parameter.

Your dataset query would them be something like

```
SELECT 
    myCategory
    , myValue * @pValue as myNewValue
    , myOtherColumns
FROM myTable
WHERE myCategory IN (@pCategory)
```

If you choose both "ABC" and "DEF" from the first parameter and "2" from your second parameter then the query that SSRS will send to the server will be

```
SELECT 
    myCategory
    , myValue * 2 as myNewValue
    , myOtherColumns
FROM myTable
WHERE myCategory IN ('ABC', 'DEF')
```

Comment: Thanks Alan, this is good idea. Other side I managed to create function to sort this out --Public Function obCatFilter(JobCats() As Object, Value() As Object, JobCat As String) As Decimal
    Dim MarginOut As Decimal = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To JobCats.Length - 1
        If Trim(LCase(JobCats(i))) = Trim(LCase(JobCat)) Then
            If Value.Length > i Then
                MarginOut = Value(i)
            Else
                MarginOut = Margin(Margin.Length - 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return MarginOut
End Function